# Vagrant, NFS, port 80 and sudo

Tags: vagrant

I have a Vagrant environment that I'd very much like to launch on port 80 using NFS. The former because it's Drupal and the non-standard port is causing a bit of heartburn and the latter purely for performance. To do that, as far as I know, I need to use `sudo`. No problem, `sudo vagrant up` it is.

The problem I'm running into is that the app generates files and, presumably because the VM was stood up under `sudo`, those files are owned by `root` on the host system (OS X) so when the app attempts to write files to the server, permission is denied.

I've altered my Vagrant file to set the entire project directory to `777`. Just for the sake of disclosure, here are the relevant (and non-standard) snippets from my `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.forward_port 80, 80
# config.vm.share_folder( "v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32/).nil?, :extra => 'dmode=777,fmode=777' )
config.vm.share_folder( "v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :extra => 'dmode=777,fmode=777' )
config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.vm.sh"
end
```

Here's what I see happening:

- When I boot up from a clean clone of the repository, no problems. Yay.

  - I do, however, notice that the content of `/vagrant`, when viewed from the VM itself, is not given full perms (`777`). This was the case before these changes.
- When I boot up after *halting* the VM...

  - Generated files can't be written.
  - Files in `/vagrant` (again, when viewed from within the VM) are owned by a `dialout` user. This seems to be an NFS thing, so no problem as long as I can get the first item to work.

**UPDATE**

Looks like the problem might be my understanding of how NFS works. I'll need to try to rectify that, but if I just remove the NFS component (now commented & replaced in the snipped above) things seem much more usable. Would still love to know if/how others may have handled this.

Comment: Its worth noting that as you are setting a hostonly network for nfs to work, you can actually access the machine on port 80 on that ip - without requiring a sudo vagrant up. So 192.168.33.10:80 should work.

Comment: While slightly unrelated, would seeding your vagrant instance with puphpet help? They have useful defaults and it is easy to configure it once generated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `sudo vagrant up` - which isn't ideal - I'm doing the following:

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 80, guest: 8080
elsif Vagrant::Util::Platform.darwin?
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 80
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8443, guest: 443
    config.trigger.after [:provision, :up, :reload] do
      puts " ==> Sudo Password (to forward ports) "
      system('echo "
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080  
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443  
    " | sudo pfctl -f - > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 8443"')  
    end
else
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 80
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8443, guest: 443
    puts " ==> Sudo Password (to forward ports) "
    system("sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80;
    sudo ipfw add 101 fwd 127.0.0.1,8443 tcp from any to me 443")
end

if Vagrant::Util::Platform.darwin?
    config.trigger.after [:halt, :destroy] do
        system("sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf > /dev/null 2>&1; echo '==> Removing Port Forwarding'")
    end
end
```

(The linux stanza of that is less neat than the OS X ("darwin") stanza, which removes the ports being forwarded on `vagrant halt`)

What this is doing is setting up port 8080 (and 8443) on the host machine to forward to 80 on the guest, and then using sudo to forward port 80 on the host machine to port 8080 on the host machine.

This means that only the port 80 forwarding is being done as root, instead of the whole vagrant process, and generally makes me happier.

Note: This will still fail on a desktop machine if skype is binding itself to ports 80 and 443, which it does by default.